# Haskell - Map a ()

Tags: haskell, dictionary

what does this line do?

```
Map a ()
```

I thought "map" is a function that works good with lists.

For example:

```
map (+1) [1,2,3] == [2,3,4]
```

But that is like

```
map :: (a->b) -> [a] -> [b] 
map f xs
```

But what does

```
map a ()
```

mean? I mean, () is no list. Never seen this before.

Comment: `Map` is not the same as `map`

Comment: `Map a ()` is a key-value pairing data structure that maps values of type `a` to the unit value `()`, which contains no information at all, other than the fact that it exists.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Map a ()` is a data type: it uses the class [Data.Map](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.4.0.0/docs/Data-Map.html) to define a data structure that maps objects of type `a` to objects of type `()`. It is similar C++'s `std::map`, Java's `HashMap`, C#'s `Dictionary`, etc.

On the other hand, [`map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) is a function. If an identifier starts with a capital letter, that means it represents a type or a class, otherwise it represents a value or a function.

**Edit:** Type `()` is a 0-tuple (or an empty tuple). If you had type `(a, b)`, that would be a 2-tuple because it can hold two elements; `(a, b, c)` would be a 3-tuple, etc. A 0-tuple is an "empty shell", it cannot hold any values. And in case you are wondering why a 0-tuple is useful, it is used mainly to indicate the absence of information.

Comment: What is an object with the type "()"? I cannot imagine what does this look like? I mean, 3 is the a, the key, right?

Comment: @fuuman `()` is a type that is only inhabited by the value `()` (same name, different things. Don't get confused by that). That is, it's something that doesn't carry any useful information. `Map a ()` is effectively equivalent to a `Set a`.

Comment: "If an identifier starts with a capital letter, that means it represents a type of a class. Otherwise it represents a value or a function." That's not quite accurate. Type variables (which are types) start with lower case letters and constructors (which are values) start with upper case letters. The distinction whether something is a type or a value depends on where it is encountered (that is if it's after a `::`, it's a type), not on what letter it starts with.

Comment: @sepp2k I probably should have made that clearer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: () is the type you use when you need a type with exactly one value. Boolean is the one when you need a type with exactly two values. You can make your own if you like via `data`, but those are already there. The point is that a Map entry takes two values; () is a good choice when you need a value with no meaning aside from assertion of its existence.

Comment: @LeviPearson Indicating the absence of information is still a very common usage and the simplest ones to describe, imo (for example, the `IO ()` type).

Comment: @PaulMarta, I was not disagreeing with you, I was just clarifying the nature of the type () and its associated value (). It inherently carries a single value, but you can use that value to *represent* a no-value situation because the real no-value type has no value; i.e. expressions of that type *can't be evaluated*; operationally, they cause program termination. A subtle distinction, but one worth knowing about.